# How get physical path of a file in a class in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a class which is not a controller, i want to get physical path of a file in a class, i know in controller easily inject `IHostingEnvironment` in its constructor and then use it:

```
   private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    //controller constructor
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
```

but when i use this way in a typical class which is not a controller i give me error in its contructor! what is the problem?

this is my class:
[image]

Comment: you should be able to take a constructor dependency on it anywhere, what is the actual error details. make sure your project.json has the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" package as a dependency

Comment: @JoeAudette please see the update

Comment: I think you should not be testing IHostingEnvironment in your unit tests, whatever you need it to do such as give you a path should be mocked with something else. I'm injecting it in a class library and it works for me there, but in unit tests there isn't really "hosting" going on. you should test that your code does what it should given specific values, testing IHostingEnvironment is Microsoft's job to test not yours. Same with HttpContext, you don't use that in unit tests you mock it

Comment: what I suggest is make your own interface IProjectPathResolver. make an implementation of that that uses IHostingEnvironment then make a MockPathResolver to use in unit tests. So your class has no direct dependency on IHostingEnvironment but only depends on your own interface IProjectPathResolver, then for testing you use a mock implementation.

Comment: I use it just for logging in test. I use xunit. And i want to get physical path of NLog.Config. assume in a traditional class i need use something like this. So if i will not get in constructor injection. so How can i get it ? According to the documents which i read about Asp.net core we just should add oue dependency in ServiceConfigure method in startup class and then inject it in your construcor and then u can use. Is it true i got it wrong?

Comment: Unit tests really should be so simple and focused, that a test failing already documents what went wrong. I would not do logging from inside unit tests. I'm not saying it cannot be done.

Comment: Please forget tbis unit test that i describe. Assume that another subject which i need to to use this class or other class.if i inject it i should access to it. So if assume this class that i use it for test i remove test methods it become to a traditional. So by this way i should access to IHostingEnvironment. But i cant. What is the problem!? I just want to find what is going wrong? Thank u for help

Comment: it does matter if it is in the context of a unit test or a running web app. as I said before it works for me to take a constructor dependency on IHostingEnvironment in a class library used in the context of a web app. I use it in a little helper library for sqlce data access to resolve the path to the db file.

Comment: Why its matter that its in the context of a unit test or running web app? Can u give more explanation, or a link for more info? Thanks alot